# PostgreSQL 12.2 - Problem with autocommit. Create a TABLESPACE

Tags: postgresql, tablespace, autocommit

I have the next error in PostgreSQL 12.2:

**"autocommit' is not recognized"**

I know that is for the version of PostgreSQL, autocommit has not effect from version 7.4.

**Anyone know how to solve this?**

I need this to create a TABLESPACE:

```
SET search_path TO textil, "$user", public;
CREATE TABLESPACE ts_txtl 
    LOCATION 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\textil\'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are using psql to do above. If so autocommit is supported:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html

"AUTOCOMMIT

When on (the default), each SQL command is 
automatically committed upon successful completion. ..."

You might want to look at if it is set in your ~/.psqlrc file.

The reason it is important is:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtablespace.html

"CREATE TABLESPACE cannot be executed inside a transaction block."